# How to move spam to spam folder?

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server, spam-prevention, spamassassin

i have already install postfix, dovecot, Clamav, Spamassassin and amavisd-new on my centos 5.10.
The tutorial is in here : http://catatanlepas.com/komputer/aplikasi/server-mail/postfix/359-instalasi-postfix-menggunakan-dovecot-di-centos-5-5

I just not install Razor, Pyzor, dan DCC on that tutorial.

Everything is work fine in /var/log/maillog, if there is a spam email n not come to inbox, but i want to move spam email to spam folder.

My Question is :
1. How to auto create spam folder on my webmail because it is just create inbox, draft and sent item only and there is no spam folder on my webmail.
2. How to move spam email to that spam folder per user (i create user on /var/vmail)

Please help me, i have search in google for a 5 days and i am stack on this :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 42):

**I - Set your email delivery to use Dovecot LDA:**

The original website the OP linked is offline, however I believe the email delivery was happening over `sendmail` program, which it should be done over Dovecot LDA for what you need. (To avoid email origin header changes).

Edit Postfix's `master.cf` (at the beginning):

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

And at the end of the file:

```
spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe
    flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e 
    /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

Now edit Postfix's `main.cf` and add (optional, check (3) bellow):

```
spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Now your email will be delivered via Dovecot LDA without header changes. For the curious ones, here are some details on my config:

1. This **config can be used with plus-addressing / sub-addressing / recipient delimiters** (emails addressed to `user+nospam@example.com` will be delivered  into `user@example.com` inbox) - That's why I added `-d ${user}@${nexthop}` this will remove the `+` and everything until the domain. To enable this feature, also be sure to add `recipient_delimiter = +` into `main.cf`;
2. My flags `flags=DROhu`, they don't add anything abnormal but they can be understood here: http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html;
3. `spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1` is required to make sure that every recipient gets individually processed by spamassassin. This is required due due to the `D` flag above (Includes `X-Original-To` header). If you don't care about this header you can remove the flag and this isn't needed.

**II - Move your SPAM to the `Junk` folder:**

(With some help from @Electronic Technologies at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470349/560745)

You can also configure Dovecot to move email detected as SPAM to the `Junk` IMAP folder. Just follow this:

1. Edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf` and uncomment / add the `Junk` folder with (should be on the `namespace inbox` section near `mailbox Trash`):

   ```
   mailbox Junk {
      special_use = \Junk
   }
   ```
2. Install `dovecot-sieve` with `apt-get install dovecot-sieve`;
3. Edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf` and comment the line: `#sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve`
4. Edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-plugin.conf` as:

   ```
   plugin {
       sieve = /etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
   }
   ```
5. Edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf` and `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-lmtp.conf` to match:

   ```
   protocol lda/lmtp { # do not copy/paste this line!
     mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
   }
   ```

   **WARNING**: You might have another settings under the `protocol` selections, keep them. The line `protocol lda/lmtp` changes in the files, keep the original.
6. Create folder `/etc/dovecot/sieve/`
7. Create file `/etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve` with this content:

   ```
   require "fileinto";
   if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
       fileinto "Junk";
   }
   ```
8. Change folder permissions to your virtual email user and group like: `chown vmail:vmail /etc/dovecot/sieve/ -R`. If you miss this dovecot will complain!
9. Restart everything: `service postfix restart; service dovecot restart; service spamassassin restart`
10. Try to send an email to some email on the server (from an external server), first a normal email and then another one with this subject: `XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X`. The second email should to into the `Junk` folder and the first to your inbox.

If this doesn't work at your first try, look at the logs: `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` and send the email while `tail` is running. A good working setup should report `stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'` or `stored mail into mailbox 'Junk'`.

Comment: This worked for me, except the `-e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}` part. It bounced with '(Uknown User)'. I did try using `-a ${recipient}` instead of `-d ${user}@${nexthop}`, but then it literally just got lost in the ether (It said it had sent, but nothing was recieved). So I just ended up using `-e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}` instead, and it works a charm :D

Comment: @Stretch apparently your dovecot configuration is different from mine. Your solution can work however you won't be able to move the email to `Junk` folder. Delivering over postfix will add extra headers to your email that you wouldn't like. Your `Unknown User` error points to a dovecot that has issues knowing what email accounts you've.. are you using virtual accounts? How's the authentication controlled? MySQL? Postfix socket?

Comment: It does send it to the Junk folder ... With your setup the mail takes the route Postfix -> Spamassassin -> Dovecot LDA -> Dovecot ... Where as mine goes Postfix -> Spamassassin -> Sendmail -> Dovecot (So the Dovecot Sieve still applies). And yeah I use virtual accounts with MySQL.

Comment: @Stretch yeah it makes sense. I was sleepy yesterday. If you don't have issues with extra headers keep it as it is. ;)

Comment: I am intrigued to know how you have your setup, because how does `/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver` know where to forward the email? I thought it needed the `-a ${recipient}` arg to know what to do with it ... Is your setup for internal email only or something? Ultimately I would like to use Dovecot LDA to handle the local delivery, but I think I'm just being fussy about sendmail Lol

Comment: @Stretch I used `sendmail` before but it adds extra headers to your email (that in some cases would not be welcome) and you're calling an extra program. Dovecot LDA exists for this situations. In my case to tell LDA what to do I'm passing `-d ${user}@${nexthop} `. According to this http://linux.die.net/man/1/dovecot-lda `-d username
Destination username. If given, the user information is looked up from userdb.` it should work then. I did that way because of the plus-addressing. `-a` should work according to the documentation (but I didn't test how it handled plus-addressing)

Comment: Dovecot-1.2 if there's a personal sieve rule, global sieve rules will be ignored. you can use "sieve_before" or "sieve_after"

Comment: I followed this guide and now dovecot doesn't work anymore. `dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Mar 31 11:41:57 ip-.. dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Mar 31 11:41:57 ip-.. dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)`

Comment: I edited `master.cf` with this: `user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e  
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}` Of course my spamassassin user is spamd...All other solutions won't work in my case. But it still doesn't move emails to junk folder. I'm using amazon SES.

Comment: @Simone I used that solution before, however it changes the headers on incoming email because you're actually sending it again using `sendmail`. Can you debug `dovecot` more? Why was it killed? What do you have on the log before that?

Comment: Some `dovecot` setups do not have `include conf.d/*.conf` in their `dovecot.conf`. I spent few hours before I realized that. And I'm not alone http://serverfault.com/a/778462/122228

Comment: You will need to add `content_filter=spamassassin` to `submission/inet` too if you want the filter to apply for it. See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSpamAssassin . Looks like `XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X` should be in message body on a separate line. See http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/

Comment: This solution works for me perfectly with one exception, spamassassin has no idea about /etc/aliases. S. [https://serverfault.com/questions/984652/mail-through-virtual-alias-and-alias-bounced-by-spamassassin-with-user-unknown]

Answer (score 8):

for Dovecot 2.1+
modify /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
namespace {
    type = private
    separator = .
    inbox = yes
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe # autocreate and autosubscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
}

plugin {
    sieve = /home/spam/default.sieve
}

protocol lda {
            auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
            mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

then /etc/postfix/master.cf - add

```
spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe
  user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e  /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

(!!) user=vmail - change the user to the one that is set up for spamassassin

and add content filter to smtp

```
smtp  inet  n  - - - -  smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

in /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf

```
add_header all Status _YESNO_, score=_SCORE_ required=_REQD_ version=_VERSION_
#rewrite_header Subject *****SPAM*****
bayes_ignore_header X-Bogosity
bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Flag
bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Status
```

I will add X-Spam headers to the message that will be used for later sieve filtering
Restart spamassassin, reload dovecot and postfix

Junk folder will be created automatically.
All Junk mail will be locally delivered to mailbox Junk


I also add an example of sieve filter to move all marked as Spam messages (spamassassin configuration above) to Junk folder.

```
require "fileinto";
  if exists "X-Spam-Flag" {
          if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "NO" {
          } else {
          fileinto "Junk";
          stop;
          }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, all emails go to the Junk folder now... Why?

Comment: @TCB13 did you solve this maybe?

Comment: I've updated my post. This is working configuration for postfix-dovecot-spamassassin

Comment: Please pay attention to the section: spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe

Comment: @pregmatch check my answer below.

Comment: Does it work only with virtual users? Any way with also real pam users?

Comment: OP mentions using amavis-new - this config may work, but not an answer. Why are you setting up spamassassin separately ? - it runs under amavis-new.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways, but this is what I've found to work. After you have postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, and (I recommend procmail) setup, you can tell procmail/spamassassin how to distrubute spam into various folders. With dovecot. I use the following 4 folders:

```
spam          (for known spam based on Bayes setting)
spam-learn    (for spam that slipped through, you move it here)
spam-probably (for spam ID'd as probably spam by Bayes setting)
spam-unlearn  (messages flagged as spam, that are NOT spam go here)
```

with the folders setup and postfix configured to filter mail through procmail with:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

you can now setup your procmailrc to put the spam in the correct place as it comes to your inbox. Your ~/.procmailrc should look something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:.
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail/
LOGDIR=$HOME/log
#DEFAULT=$HOME/Mail/
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/procmail.log
VERBOSE=ON
## with spamc
:0fw: spamc.lock
* < 256000
| spamc
#| /usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc
# Mails with a score of 15 or higher are almost certainly spam (with 0.05%
# false positives according to rules/STATISTICS.txt). Let's put them in a
# different mbox. (This one is optional.)
:0:
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
spam
#Mail/spam

# All mail tagged as spam (eg. with a score higher than the set threshold)
# is moved to "probably-spam".
:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
spam-probably
#Mail/spam-probably

# Work around procmail bug: any output on stderr will cause the "F" in "From"
# to be dropped.  This will re-add it.
:0
* ^^rom[ ]
{
LOG="*** Dropped F off From_ header! Fixing up. "

:0 fhw
| sed -e '1s/^/F/'
}
```

Now the final key to making it all work automatically is to use `fetchmail` to scan messages as they arrive in your inbox handing off to procmail to put the spam/spam probably in the right folders and to read the messages in the spam (to delete) and spam-unlearn (to learn as `ham`). A typical fetchmail script to do with is your ~/.fetchmailrc. It will simply contain commands to poll your mailbox:

```
poll mail.yourserver.com protocol IMAP : user yourname with password yourpass ssl \
sslfingerprint "D9:73:1A:FE:C6:7C:E7:9B:F1:31:F8:A1:A0:E1:F9:27"
```

(you can get your server fingerprint by simple running `fetchmail --verbose` against your .fetchmailrc file and it will print the server fingerprint, check your current one, tell you they don't match and close the connection -- but -- you just got the correct fingerprint for next time :-)

Lastly, set up a couple of cron jobs to run this whole thing by reading your spam-learn and spam-unlearn folders. Hourly is good enough. The script can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## log file location and per-user name
LDIR=/home/admin/log
LFN="${LDIR}/${USER}.log"

## Retrieve and Process Spam & Ham from 'spam-learn' & 'spam-unlearn' folders
/usr/bin/fetchmail -a -s -n --folder spam-learn -m '/usr/bin/vendor_perl/sa-learn --spam' &>/dev/null
mss=$?
sleep 2
/usr/bin/fetchmail -a -s -n --folder spam-unlearn -m '/usr/bin/vendor_perl/sa-learn --ham' &>/dev/null
mhs=$?

## test and create log dir in noexist
[[ -d "$LDIR" ]] || mkdir -p "$LDIR"
if [[ -w "$LDIR" ]]; then

## check return from fetchmail and write log info
if [[ $(($mhs+$mss)) -le 2 ]]; then
    echo "$(date +'%b %e %R:%S') $HOSTNAME ${0##*/}: sa-learn completed successfully for user $USER" >>$LFN
else
    echo "$(date +'%b %e %R:%S') $HOSTNAME ${0##*/}: sa-learn FAILED for user $USER" >>$LFN
fi
fi
```

And the cron job simply execute the spamv.sh file above:

```
05 * * * * /usr/local/bin/spamv.sh
```

I have run servers like this for nearly a decade and it works well. The training files reside in the user's home dir and can be easily moved box-to-box to provide a good base set for new users. Good luck. I did a short howto on this setup years ago for [openSuSE 11.0](http://www.3111skyline.com/linux/openSuSE-server.php). There may be a little more info there as well.

P.S.  Rayzor is worth loading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. David. When i want to install procmail, in my centos 5.10 already installed procmail. What should i do ? I search for /etc/procmailrc but i found nothing on /etc/ there is no procmailrc. I don't find anything about procmail on my virtual user directory too, /var/vmail/(domain)/(username)/Maildir/ I'm confused to search it. Should i uninstall procmail first or what should i do ? Thank you :)

Comment: There is no `/etc/procmailrc` by default, but if you create one, Procmail will use it.

Comment: The procmailrc file is ~/.procmailrc -- sorry for the confusion